# Kendo dropdown showing value after selection in grid with incell editing, MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd appreciate any help.
My model:

```
 public class AddressModel
 {
     public int AddressID { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }     
     public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
 }
 public class AddressType
 {   
     public string Code{get; set;}
     public string Title{get; set;}
 }
```

I have a grid with incell editing:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AddressModel>(Model.Addresses)
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Type)
           .EditorTemplateName("AddressTypes");
           //.ClientTemplate("#=AddressType.Title#"); //not working

})
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
{
    toolBar.Create();
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))    =
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(model =>
{
    model.Id(p => p.AddressID);
    model.Field(p => p.AddressID).Editable(false);
}))
```

Editor template:

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("Type").BindTo(new SelectList(context.AddressTypes, "Code", "Title"))
```

The problem is when I select some item, dropdown shows selected value instead of text. I need to show the `Title`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As per describes on kendo forums.

1. Editor name must match the property name in the grid model
2. Must be bind ViewBag, DataSource, or static

   ```
   public class AddressModel
   {

       public int AddressID { get; set; }    
       public string Type { get; set; }      
       public AddressTypeModel AddressType { get; set;}
   }
   public class AddressTypeModel
   {   
       public string Code{get; set;}
        public string Title{get; set;}
   }      

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AddressModel>(Model.Addresses)
     .Name("grid")
     .Columns(columns =>
       {
      columns.Bound(p => p.Type)
      .EditorTemplateName("AddressTypesListEditor");
      .ClientTemplate("#=AddressType.Title#"); //should work

      })
       .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
    toolBar.Create();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))    =
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .Model(model =>
    {
      model.Id(p => p.AddressID);
      model.Field(p => p.AddressID).Editable(false);
    }))
   ```

Editor template:

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("AddressType")// Name of the widget should be the same the property    
.HtmlAttributes( new {@class=".k-dropdown-wrap-custom"})
.Events(e => { e.Select("AddressTypeSelected");})   
.BindTo(ViewBag.AddressTypeList)
```

Server side:

```
   List<AddressTypeModel> list=   _unitOfWork.AdminRepository.GetAddressTypes().Select(t =>
            new AddressTypeModel
            {
                 Code= t.Code.toString(),
                 FundName = t.Title.toSTring()
            }).ToList();


        ViewBag.AddressTypeList = list;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you pls clarify, why you bind a list instead of SelectList. Also, I get an error: 'AddressType is not defined' because of ClientTemplate("#=AddressType.Title#")